# wordpress plugin boilerplate to use a placeholder

Tags: wordpress, placeholder, boilerplate

I'm developing a plugin using the wordpress plugin boilerplate and I'm trying to create a function to use a placeholder inside the page content, but nothing happens.
This is the code:

```
//class-annuncifunebri-public.php
public function annuncio_register_shortcode() {
    $plugin = new Annunci_Funebri_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
    add_shortcode( 'ANNUNCIFUNEBRI_ANNUNCIO', array( $plugin, 'annuncio_shortcode' ) );
}

public function annuncio_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    require_once( 'partials/annuncio.php' );
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $content;
}

//class-annuncifunebri.php
private function define_public_hooks() {
    $plugin_public = new Annunci_Funebri_Public( $this->get_plugin_name(), $this->get_version() );
    ...
    $this->loader->add_action('init', $plugin_public, 'annuncio_register_shortcode');
}
```